# Whats the best way to check for the existence of a document which contains a field with a specific value - Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to check if a field `nam` has a specific value and return a boolen if true(or check by something else - whatever).
Here is my code which actually does check but still returns something (some autogenerated stuff from the server) and if I check for `null` of course it will never be null.

So, whats the easiest and best way to do this? And is it better to do it server-side? P.S. I want to inform the user that a field with this value was found!

Here is my current code:

```
var type_of_vendor = db().collection(this.state.vendor_type).where('nam', '==', this.state.vendor_name);
type_of_vendor.get()
    .then((user) => {
        if (user.exists) {
            this.state.error = true;
            let errorMessage = 'error message';
            this.setState({ errorMessage: errorMessage });
        } else {
            this._signUpVendorvalidateHandler();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. The only think I'd change is add `.limit(1)` to the query, so that you never retrieve more than 1 document, even if there are multiple matches.

Doing this server-side is possible with either Cloud Functions, or on a server you already control.

If you do this on the server, you will only have to return whether the document exists (a boolean), instead of the entire document. So you're saving some bandwidth there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you give a code example how to do that in server-side?

Comment: That depends on where you run the code. In Cloud Functions for Firebase you'd use Node.js, so the code would be quite similar to what you have now.

Comment: How do I call that function from RN?

Comment: For example like this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable. At this point I recommend you read the documentation, find some tutorial of your liking on building Cloud Functions, and try building it yourself. If you get stuck, post back with the [concrete code of where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can try to help further.

Comment: alright thanks, do you think its a good idea to use Functions for the entire authentication operation? I need to read and write in several documents when registering a new user but I am doing all this in RN code.